# How to get total amount per previous weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have this table for example:

| Date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-16T21:06:38 | 10 |
| 2021-02-16T21:07:01 | 5 |
| 2021-02-17T01:10:12 | -1 |
| 2021-02-19T12:00:00 | 3 |
| 2021-02-24T12:00:00 | 20 |
| 2021-02-25T12:00:00 | -1 |

I want the total amount of all previous weeks, per week. So the result in this case would be:

| Date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-15 | 0 |
| 2021-02-22 | 17 |
| 2021-03-01 | 36 |

**Note:** The dates are now the start of each week (Monday).
Any help would this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
select week_date, sum(amount) over (order by week_date ) 
from (
SELECT date(date_) + cast(abs(extract(dow FROM date_) -7 ) + 1 as int) "week_date",
sum(amount) "amount"
from example group by 1) t
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d6e68671475a489150028075d8cd5143)

Above Query will cover only the week in which transaction records are there. If you want to cover all missing week then try below query:

```
with cte as (
SELECT date(date_) + cast(abs(extract(dow FROM date_) -7 ) + 1 as int) "week_date",
sum(amount) "amount"
from example group by 1
)
select 
t1."Date",coalesce(sum(cte.amount) over (order by t1."Date"),0)
from cte right join 
(select generate_series(min(week_date)- interval '1 week', max(week_date),interval '1 week') "Date" from cte) t1 on cte.week_date=t1."Date"
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=16ac0574a40dc73ec6828aabd99fd0f1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `generate_series()` to generate the dates you want.  Then use `left join` to bring in the data and aggregate with a cumulative sum:

```
select gs.week,
       coalesce(sum(e.amount), 0) as week_amount,
       sum(coalesce(sum(e.amount), 0)) over (order by gs.week) as running_amount
from generate_series('2021-02-15'::date, '2021-03-01'::date, interval '1 week') gs(week) left join
     example e
     on e.date < gs.week and
        e.date >= gs.week - interval '1 week'
group by gs.week
order by gs.week;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f407497fcf3ce87dfc78669c1b93967) is a db<>fiddle.